# Jboss 7 getResourcesAsStream()

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee, jboss, jboss7.x

Application structure description: Ear application with ejb module (.jar), jboss-seam (.jar) and war module (.war).

I have a `StartupAction.class` (seam component) annotated with `org.jboss.seam.annotations.Startup`. During application deployment I need to get the resource from application.war module root (*application.war/pages/page.xhtml*) and `WEB-INF/classes` (*application.war/WEB-INF/classes/file.properties*)

- **Jboss 4.2** 
  `Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("file.properties")` would fetch the file from *application.war/WEB-INF/classes/file.properties.*
- **Jboss 7.1.1**
  Code from above doesn't work with Jboss 7.

I know that the class loading changed but I can't figure it out how to get into *application.war* in jboss 7.

Is it possible to do this? Are there any example of this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where exactly is `StartupAction` itself located? The EAR/EJB module is in first place never supposed to be able to access resources from WAR nor to use its dependencyes. It's only the other way round.

Comment: `StartupAction` is in application.jar in _company....action_ package. All classes are there. On startup it calls a `StartupService` which is responsible for fetching the file and importing the properties into the database. I'm migrating seam app from jboss 4 to jboss 7. If there is another way to do this (get file at startup) i could re-implement it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by @BalusC, you will not be able to read a properties file that is embedded in a web module from any other modules (EJB or otherwise) that are packaged in your EAR.

The fact that this works in JBoss 4.x is a consequence of it providing backwards compatibility for even earlier versions of JBoss. Additional configuration is required in JBoss 4.x in order for it to use specification compliant class loading. JBoss 7.x and newer use specification compliant class loading by default.

If your properties file contains external configuration that is intended to be accessible after deployment then you might consider the approach described in [How to put an external file in the classpath](https://developer.jboss.org/docs/DOC-18247).

However, if it is effectively static data then you should package the properties file in a jar module and place it in the the lib directory of your EAR.

Comment: I packaged my properties into jar file and moved it to the application.ear/lib folder. In `StartupAction` code `Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(file.properties)` works now.

I believe that this will be an acceptable solution.

Answer (score 0):

In jboss7, you have a classloader for each subdeploy.

In your case, `Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()` will return the classloader of the current deployment.

To fix your problem, you could try this:
`SomeRandomClassContainedInsideTheWAR.class.getClassLoader()`

Check this guide to learn more about JBoss7 ClassLoader
https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS7/Class+Loading+in+AS7

Comment: Problem is that I don't have classes inside war. All my classes are in application-ejb.jar module. 
I do have one class in war module which is not used and I tried there  SomeRandomClassContainedInsideTheWAR.class.getClassLoader().getResources(...) didn't work. It returns null.

Comment: Have you tried with `"/file.properties"`, or `"/WEB-INF/classes/file.properties"` instead of "file.properties" ?